# use dispatch outside react component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit, react-typescript

I am adding new feature to my react app, I want to add the capability to log from anywhere (including non-react components), so I want to dispatch an action from anywhere in the app.

The problem is when I want to dispatch the logging action from non-components files, I have to import the store to access to the dispatch method, and it provokes circular import dependency errors in certain case.

The [docs](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-can-i-use-the-redux-store-in-non-component-files) recommend using middleware or thunk in this use case, but I can't figure out how to use them for my use case, since to trigger them, it requires to dispatching an action in the first place.

For now, I have a workaround that "works":

```
// outside the component 
let dispatch :AppDispatch;

// I can invoke this function from anywhere
export const addLogMessage = (message: ProgressMessage) => {dispatch(progressMessageAdded(message))}
...
...
// inside the component
dispatch = useDispatch();
```

But I think it's not the convenient way to do it...

What is the best solution to dispatch a redux action outside reacts components without importing the redux store?

Comment: why don't you follow this method from docs: Expose an injectStore function from the interceptor file instead

Comment: if I do, I will have to use injectStore in different places.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you have to use Selector, that particular selector will help you make use it into another component.